# TYPO3 MenuProcessor with dynamic uid

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I want to use the MenuProcessor dynamic in my fluidtemplate.
Configured in TypoScript, I want to call it with the cObject ViewHelper and pass the uid of a page to it:
`{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.menuTest', data:{menuId:'28'})}`

This is what I have tried - it should be a `special = directory` with the the given uid in `special.value = XXXXXX`.

```
lib {
    menuTest = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    menuTest {
        templateName = MenuTest
        templateRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:hatemplate/Resources/Private/Templates/
        }

        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
            10 {
                special = directory
                special.value = XXXXXX
                levels = 1
                as = menuItems
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I set a uid directly it works, but I don't know how to insert the variable. Has anyone a hint or a working solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with the help of a friend who is much more experienced in TypoScript.

I wasn't as wrong as I thought.

This is the Code in TypoScript. I added the tamplate,layout and partial paths for future copy/pasting :) :

```
lib {
    menuDirectory = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    menuDirectory {
        templateName = MenuDirectory
        layoutRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:hatemplate/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        }
        templateRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:hatemplate/Resources/Private/Templates/
        }
        partialRootPaths {
            10 = EXT:hatemplate/Resources/Private/Partials/
        }

        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
            10 {
                special = directory
                special.value.field = menuId
                levels = 1
                as = directory
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this configured you can use the `f:cObject` ViewHelper like this:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.menuDirectory" data="{menuId:1}" />
```

Or inline

```
{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.menuDirectory', data:{menuId:1})}
```

This renders the Items into the fluidtemplate:

[image]